# Load a component in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I got a problem and can't find the solution. Sorry if it's a dumb one but I'm a newby with React.

I want to dynamically load a component inside useEffect hook. I can load the file but cant access the function.

Here is my main file

**footer.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState}  from "react";

const MyMainComponent = ({ type }) => {

const [preFooter,setPreFooter ] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if (type === "page") {
      import( "./prefooter/preFooterPage")
      .then(PreFooterPage =>
       setPreFooter(result)
      );
    } else {
      import( "./prefooter/preFooterArticle")
      .then(x =>
        setPreFooter(result)
      );
    }
  }, [type]);

return (
//I want to use the result like this : <preFooter/>
...
)

}

export default MyMainComponent
```

Here are the two different components :

**preFooterArticle.js**

```
import React from "react";

const PreFooterArticle = () => {

return (
<h2>Hi, I'm a pre Footer for blog posts !</h2>
)

}

export default PreFooterArticle
```

**preFooterPage.js**

```
import React from "react";

const PreFooterPage = () => {

return (
<h2>Hi, I'm a pre Footer for pages !</h2>
)

}

export default PreFooterPages
```

The import and set state work fine but I dont know how return the state as a component ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Why not importing the components at the top, then just `type === "page" ? <PreFooterPages/> : < PreFooterArticle/>` in the return statement of `MyMainComponent`?

Comment: It's actually what I'm doing but it is importing both files which impacts the performances

Comment: What's the performance problem you are facing? I doubt loading an additional 20 lines component would have a big impact in the final bundle!

Comment: You're re right but in fact my components Article and Page are much more than 20 lines, I just simplified to get the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the dynamic import is loaded, you need to supply a default component state (`() => null`), since `useState` treats any functions passed in init as [initializer](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters), you'll need to wrap it in another function (`() => () => null`).

When you import a file, you get an object, with the actual imports as properties of the object, so you need to extract your component (`{ default: comp }`). Then you set it on your state, and again need to wrap it with a function, so it won't be treated as an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) - `setPreFooter(() => comp)`.

Code ([Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/manual-lazy-load-lmyqyg?file=/src/App.js:77-601)):

```
const MyMainComponent = ({ type }) => {
  const [PreFooter, setPreFooter] = useState(() => () => null); // default state should be a component that renders null

  useEffect(() => {
    const url =
      type === 'page'
        ? './prefooter/preFooterPage'
        : './prefooter/preFooterArticle';

    import(url).then(
      (
        { default: comp } // get the import from the returned object
      ) => setPreFooter(() => comp) // use updater function to set in state
    );
  }, [type]);

  return <PreFooter />;
};
```

However, instead of inventing the wheel, you can use [React.lazy](https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy) to load the component dynamically, and wrap it with  to provide a fallback until the component is loaded.

Code ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lazy-load-forked-8lq395?file=/src/App.js)):

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

const PreFooterPage = lazy(() => import('./prefooter/preFooterPage'));
const PreFooterArticle = lazy(() => import('./prefooter/preFooterArticle'));

const MyMainComponent = ({ type }) => (
  <Suspense fallback="Loading">
    {type === 'page' ? <PreFooterPage /> : <PreFooterArticle />}
  </Suspense>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return a state as a component use redux.

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

> Redux is more useful when:
>
> You have large amounts of application state that are needed in many
> places in the app.
> The app state is updated frequently over time.
> The
> logic to update that state may be complex.
> The app has a medium or
> large-sized codebase, and might be worked on by many people

As example, the index.js should look like this:`import React from

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import {StrictMode} from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';





import store from './redux/redux-store'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);



let rerenderEntireTree = (state) => {

  console.log(state)
  root.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App state={state} dispatch={store.dispatch.bind(store)} store={store}/>
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root')
  )

}

rerenderEntireTree(store.getState())
store.subscribe(() => {
  let state = store.getState()
  rerenderEntireTree(state)

})`
```

The rerenderEntireTree function helps to rerender as the state changes as well as subscribe

and create reducer files as for example this:

```
let initialState = {
    sidebar: {}
}

const sidebarReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    
    return state;
}

export default sidebarReducer
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).